# Vim Visual Select around Variables

Tags: vim

I'm wondering if there's a way to select variables intelligently in the same way that one can select blocks using commands like `va}`. There's some language-specific parsing going on to differentiate php and ruby, for example. For future reference, It'd be nice to tap into that - ideally selecting around various syntactic elements.

For example. I'd like to select around `$array['testing']` in the following line of php:

```
$array['testing'] = 'whatever'
```

Or, lets say I want to select the block parameter list `|item, index|` here:

```
hash.each_with_index { |item, index| print item }
```

---

EDIT:

Specific regexps might address the various questions individually, but I have a sense that there *ought* to be a way to leverage syntactic analysis to get something far more robust here.

Answer (score 3):

Though your given examples are quick to select with built-in Vim text objects (the first is just `viW`, for the second I would use `F|v,`), I acknowledge that Vim's syntax highlighting could be a good source for motions and text objects.

I've seen the first implementation of this idea in the [SyntaxMotion plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2965), and I've recently implemented a similar plugin: [SameSyntaxMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4338). The first defines motions for normal and visual mode, but no operator-pending and text objects. It does not skip over contained sub-syntax items and uses same color as the distinguishing property, whereas mine uses syntax (which can be more precise, but also more difficult to grasp), and has text objects (`ay` and `iy`), too.

Answer (score 2):

You can **define your own arbitrary text objects** in Vim.

The simplest way to do custom text objects is defining a `:vmap` (or `:xmap`) for the Visual mode part and an `:omap` for the Operator-pending mode part. For example, the following mappings

```
xnoremap aC F:o,
onoremap aC :normal! F:v,<CR>
```

let you select a colon-enclosed bit of text. Try doing `vaP` or `daP` on the word "colon" below:

```
Some text :in-colon-text: more of the same.
```

See [`:h omap-info`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#omap-info) for another short example of `:omap`.

---

If you don't mind depending on a **plugin**, however, there is [***textobj-user***](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2100). This is a general purpose framework for custom text objects written by Kana Natsuno. There are already some excellent text objects written for that framework like [*textobj-indent*](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2484) which I find indispensable.

Using this you can easily implement filetype-dependent text objects for variables. And make it available for everybody!